# POS Application Couchbase vs CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, desktop, offline, couchbase, cloudant

I need to design a cloud based POS application, but the customer is demanding that the app should also have some offline facilities and work offline on Mobile platforms and Desktop Platforms too. (Sales should not stop even if there is no internet connection)

At first sight I chose Couchbase as the database, JAVA EE + Spring for the back-end + JSF for the frontend.

For the mobile I was thinking about Xamarin + Couchbase Lite which should sync with the Couchbase on the cloud.

My main problem is when Desktop is offline. From what I understood since I read about these databases, Couchbase Lite is just for the mobile.

What configuration do you suggest for this situation? so even when the desktop goes offline, it still has some data available, and it will sync with the cloud when it's back online.
Maybe I should change my mind to CouchDB ? Which one is better ?

I am a bit noob in this area, it's my first cloud based project, I am reading a lot in the last few days, and I really want to do it because I want to learn these things as this part is growing a lot in the last years.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couchbase lite can run on desktops. the list here gives you the option to run on windows or in JVM capable desktop: http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/#couchbase-lite. I'd recommend mobile for the desktop side.